# Unique visit per IP and dates

Tags: php, laravel, group-by

I have two tables: users and visits, I'm storing in visit tables how many users visited site (Offer model has many Visits) how to count unique visits by IP for all time? $offer->visits->groupBy('ip')->count() return number of views for IP of all time. I want to see all the unique visits for all days, eg.

User has IP 192.168.0.1
He visited one site:

```
25.04.2020 - He visited once.
26.04.2020 - He visited 3 times.

groupBy('ip')->count() - returns 1 view.
```

I want to return 2 views (because of unique one visit per date)

How to do that?

Comment: can you provide migrations or table structures for both users and visits

Answer (score 0):

You will need to groupBy today's date & IP for your relation. You can achieve that by using:

```
    $offers = Offer::with(['visits' => function ($query) {
                $query->select(DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as date'), 'ip','offer_id')
                      ->groupBy('date', 'ip');
              }])
              ->get();

    foreach ($offers as $offer){
       dump($offer->visits);
    }
```

Comment: have you checked what is the `$offers` Collection returning?

Comment: Yep, it's returning normal collection of Offer Models.

Comment: On a more general view, keep in mind that we are trying to help you - this should be more of a constructive discussion while it does feel like you behave like an interviewer quizzing for an interview. That being said, I reformulate my question, is there anything on the `$offers` collection that can say we are on the right track?

Comment: I tried your solution. I made exactly what You said. In foreach i returned $offer->visits->count(); and it shows: 0. I dumped records (dump($offer->visits)) from foreach, It shows empty collection of views. Normally $offer shows all information about added offert, that works, but count views not.

Comment: Are you sure that the `$offer` you are dumping has visits?

Comment: yes, I'm 100% sure, to be sure i checked again, and yes, they have visits

Comment: Ooh I forgot the `->get()` in my query. Please have a look at the updated answer

Comment: You forget about ->get() but i don't. Still doesn't work

Comment: Alright, I tried - let's see if someone smarter can come up with a solution

Comment: Please check the updated answer, it will work. If you are satisfied, please approve the answer 